# Evaluating multiple expression using th:if in Thymeleaf

Tags: if-statement, thymeleaf

I am wondering what the correct syntax for multiple expressions within th:if in Thymeleaf is.
So far I have something like this:

```
<a style="color:blue" th:href="@{/approveAndJoin/{name}(name=${outbox.receiverName})}" th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(outbox.status, 'P')}">Join Team?!</a>
```

What would the correct syntax be to do something like this:
(Pseudo code)

```
th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(outbox.status, 'P') && #strings.startsWith(inbox.status, 'A'}"
```

I have read through the various manuals but have not discovered how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine several conditions with the keyword `and`

e.g. in your case  `th:if="${not #strings.startsWith(outbox.status, 'P') and #strings.startsWith(inbox.status, 'A'}"`